# Listview and ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, listview, imageswitcher

My layout contains a LinearLayout on top and has two childrens - RelativeLayout and ListView. The RelativeLayout contains a ImageSwitcher. I have observed that when listview is being populated, the ImageSwitcher takes the whole screen and then shrinks once the listview is visible. Is it possible to avoid the effect? Here is my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6" >

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/image_anim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera_black" >
    </ImageSwitcher>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_anim"
        android:background="#aa000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
        android:textColor="#ffeeeeee" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: The whole layout is inside a linearlayout with weightsum of 10

Comment: Image switcher height and width is Match parent...change it to wrap content and try it

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android it worked then .. but then the images that are small in size will make the imageswitcher smaller. But i want my imageswitcher to always be half the screensize

Comment: You can use Linear Layout within Relative layout...or you can use scale_type = fitXY in Imageview.

Comment: its imageswitcher not imageview .. there is no scale_type property @Swap-IOS-Android